# Why is my function triggering multiple times?

Tags: python, pyautogui

This code:

1. Looks for an image `a`
2. If it finds `a` it tries to find a match for any image in the array
   `image_list`
3. If it finds an image in `image_list` it looks for `e`
4. If it finds `e` it logs it and moves the mouse to `x, y` checks for pixel colour and then clicks when when it finds a match, clicks.

This is where my problem arises my `avoidLog()` function is being called 2-3 times per click. I've added `print("click")` to check if it's actually clicking and it isn't, it's clicking at the right time but for some reason, my log is triggering more than once.

It's logging correctly, just an odd number of times.

I know python is operating in a single thread in my example so I'm not sure why it's looping back round and *not* clicking. It would make more sense to me if it was clicking multiple times and logging multiple times.

```
import pyautogui as py

def avoidLog():
   avoidLog = open('Avoided.txt', 'a')
   avoidLog.write("Found at: " + str(f) + " at: " + str(skipTime))
   avoidLog.write("\n")
   avoidLog.close()

image_list = []
while True:
        if py.locateOnScreen('a.jpg') != None:                       
               for image in image_list:                                          
                    found = py.locateCenterOnScreen(image)

                    if found != None:
                         skipTrigger = py.locateOnScreen('e.jpg')

                         if skipTrigger != None:
                              avoidLog()
                              py.moveTo(x, y)                                                                                           
                              r = py.pixelMatchesColor(x,y, (r,g,b))

                              if r == True:
                                   py.sleep(2)
                                   print("click")
                                   py.click()
                                   break
```

Comment: Where do you define `f` and `skipTime`?

Comment: why is `avoidLog` both a function and a variable?

Comment: First of all, have a think about what's going to happen if a.jpg cannot be located! Secondly, avoidLog() is called whenever e.jpg is located. However, py.click() is only called if pixelMatchesColor is True

Comment: Cheers @DarkKnight yeah there's a whole few hundred other lines of code that I didn't include for the sake of the example but if you could post that up as the answer please. You're spot on avoidLog() is getting called whenever is e found ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

avoidLog() is called whenever e.jpg is located. However, py.click() is only called if pixelMatchesColor is True